# Core Data: updating configuration with a migration

Tags: ios, core-data, migration

At the moment I've 2 different store configurations:

**A:** Local to the client device

**B:** Local to the client device and Synched with iCloud

In the next version of my App I want to merge some of the entities in the configuration A into the configuration B.

I can't find any useful information to perform this operation without losing user data. 
I'll try to give you some more details:

Let's say that these are the schemas of my configurations:

```
Configuration A entities:
- Entity_1
- Entity_2
- Entity_3

Configuration B entities:
- Entity_4
```

I want to end up with this single configuration:

```
Configuration A entities:
- Entity_1
- Entity_2
- Entity_3
- Entity_4
```

The current code that I've used to initialise the stores is the next:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

// Define the stores URLS
    NSURL *store_A_URL = [[self databaseFolder] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"StoreA.sqlite"];

    NSURL *store_B_URL = [[self databaseFolder] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"StoreB.sqlite"];

    NSError *error = nil;

    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

// iCloud sync store config
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                   configuration:@"Config_A"
                                                             URL:store_A_URL
                                                         options:@{NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey:@"Store"}
                                                           error:&error]) {

    /// Error management

    }    

// Local only store config
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType
                                                   configuration:@"Config_B"
                                                             URL:store_B_URL
                                                         options:0
                                                           error:&error]) {

    /// Error management

    }

    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

My question is: "how can I perform the migration of the entities of store_B to be included into store_A and so automatically synched with iCloud?"

**EDIT:**

I wonder if adding the NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey option to "Store B" would be enough to have it synched on iCloud... leaving the 2 different configurations... 
What do you think about that?